# How to Execute AfterMehtod for only one Test method

Tags: java, automation, testng

I have to `Test` methods in my code and I wan to execute `AfterMehtod` for only one. Anybody have any idea how do this?

Here is My code:

```
package Demo;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import library.Utility;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Pages.custom_actions_page;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class Custom_Actions extends start {

    ExtentReports report;
    ExtentTest logger;
    String driverPath = "D:\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe";

    @Test()
    public void signin() throws Exception {

        // To Locate the Username field
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");

        // To locate the Password field
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin123");

        // Click on Login button
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "signin" })
    public void create_custom_action() {
        report = new ExtentReports("D:/Reports/Report.html");

        logger = report.startTest("Create Custom Action");

        new custom_actions_page(driver).submit();

        new custom_actions_page(driver).admin();

        new custom_actions_page(driver).custom_ac();

        new custom_actions_page(driver).createnew();

        new custom_actions_page(driver).nameAs("fortesting").descriptionAs(
                "description");

        new custom_actions_page(driver).category();

        new custom_actions_page(driver).assetsubtype();

        new custom_actions_page(driver).assettype();

        new custom_actions_page(driver).flintnameAs("hello:example.rb");

        new custom_actions_page(driver).submit_butto();

        new custom_actions_page(driver).Save_Button();

        logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Custom Action Created Successfully");
    }

    @AfterMethod()
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {

        // Here will compare if test is failing then only it will enter into if
        // condition
        if (ITestResult.FAILURE == result.getStatus()) {
            try {

                Utility.captureScreenshot(driver, "CustomActionFail.png");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot "
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        report.endTest(logger);
        report.flush();
        driver.close();
    }}
```

Comment: Just a tip: keep package names lowercase and class names start with a capital letter! (extends start).

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire - Thanks for your tip.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire - Hey, Can you help me out with one scenario? In above code, I have two Test methods and I want to run AfterMethod for one only. Do you have any idea how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a good practice to completely change the question after it has been posted. If you want to ask another question, create a new question. It makes tracking questions and answer very difficult when things change this drastically.

Comment: @JeffC - My apologies for the inconvenience caused. Will take care next time.

Answer (score 0):

`@AfterMethod` is designed to make your life easier when you need to execute a the same block of code after each test without having to duplicate it in each test. So if you need it to execute only after one test, just embed it into that `@Test` method and remove the `@AfterMethod` annotated method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing it using what is called as `Native Injection` within TestNG. For more details on what is the possible combinations for native injection in TestNG please refer [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/Allowed-parameters-injection-in-methods).

The simplest way would be to inspect the name of the `@Test` method that is about to be executed, from within your `@AfterMethod` annotated method, and if it matches the name of the method for which you need special execution, you proceed further, else you skip executing the `@AfterMethod`.
But this is a primitive approach, because if you refactor your test method's name to something else, your approach gets broken.

The other approach is to basically work with a marker interface and do the same logic as described above

Here's a sample that shows all this in action.

The marker annotation would look like below

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface NeedsSpecialSetup {
}
```

Now your test class would look like below

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class SampleTestClass {

    @NeedsSpecialSetup
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        System.err.println("Executing testMethod1()");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        System.err.println("Executing testMethod2()");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(Method method) {
        NeedsSpecialSetup needsSpecialSetup = method.getAnnotation(NeedsSpecialSetup.class);
        if (needsSpecialSetup == null) {
            //Don't execute this setup because the method doesn't have the
            //special setup annotation.
            return;
        }
        System.err.println("Running special setup for " + method.getName() + "()");
    }
}
```

Notice how we have added the annotation `@NeedsSpecialSetup` only for the method `testMethod1()` to indicate that we need the `@AfterMethod` to be executed only for `testMethod1()`.

Here's the output

```
Executing testMethod1()

Running special setup for testMethod1()
Executing testMethod2()

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Interesting. Coz I thought by default anyone who posts a question should be able to accept a reply as an answer irrespective of their reputation